# Using PowerBI calculated columns vs calculated measures to calculate a frequency flag column

Tags: data, powerbi

Sorry for the long question.

In PowerBI I have fields called 'user ID' and 'service'. Each row represents an activity, so may not be unique. I want to create a new variable called '5+ flag' that for each ID, counts how many times it appears and then assigns 1 if it five or more, and 0 otherwise.

Eventually I would like to use this variable in a calculated measure that counts the number of rows with a '5+ contacts' = 1 and certain value for 'service' and divides it by the number of unique IDs with '5+ contacts' = 1. The DAX code for this measure is below:

measure_1 = DIVIDE(
COUNTROWS(
FILTER(
'data',
'data'[5+ flag] = 1 &&
'data'[service] = "Design"
)
),
CALCULATE(
DISTINCTCOUNT(
'data'[userID]),
'data'[5+ flag] = 1
)
)

Unfortunately, when I tried making '5+ flag' using a calculated column (using DAX code below), I got the incorrect values. Although measure_1 did work. I believe this has something to do with calculated columns being fixed and not dynamic.

5+ flag =
IF(
CALCULATE(
COUNTROWS('Merged data'),
FILTER(
'Merged data',
'Merged data'[patient ID] = EARLIER('Merged data'[patient ID]) &&
'Merged data'[stage of care] = "05 Chemotherapy"
)
) >= 5,
1,
0
)

When I tried making it using a calculated measure (using DAX code below), I got the correct numbers, but then measure_1 gave this error: 'A function 'PLACEHOLDER' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.'

5+ contacts =
SUMX(
VALUES('Merged data'[Patient ID]),
CALCULATE(COUNT('Merged data'[Patient ID]))
)

Could anyone tell me how to either get the correct numbers for '5+ contacts' as a calculated column, or how to get measure_1 working when '5+ contacts' is a calculated measure. Any advice would be really appreciated.